# Is it possible for two applications to use the framebuffer simultaneously?

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame, framebuffer, navit

I'm developing a dashboard computer for my car based on a Raspberry Pi and a touchscreen. The GUI is based on PyGame so it can write directly to the framebuffer, which works fine.

However, I'm looking to integrate the navigation software Navit into my solution. Navit can be configured to output to the framebuffer too, which also works fine when running it.

Now to my question: Is it possible to run both applications at the same time, simultaneously using the framebuffer? My idea is that you start the PyGame GUI in fullscreen and then sets the Navit screen to say 20% less width so that my GUI buttons are visible along the edges and writing it's graphics at a time each. Is this even doable?

NB: I know it is possible to embed Navit into my GUI as per http://wiki.navit-project.org/index.php/Embedding, but that requires me to use PyQt which I don't want to do since I already have developed everything in PyGame and don't want to be dependent on X and other graphics.

Any ideas of other solutions appreciated if I'm completely out sailing here.